# What is the range in terms of distance of MCSession?

Tags: multipeer-connectivity, mcsession

I am developing mobile application which use MCSession to get list of near by users. So i am wondering what is range of MCSession?

Answer (score 0):

Multipeer Connectivity is using the onboard radios Bluetooth and WiFi and is therefore limited by their range.

A quick online search can return interesting results as to the range of those radio technologies.

Here is a good overview of Multipeer Connectivity by NSHipster:

> Multipeer Connectivity is a framework that enables nearby devices to communicate over infrastructure Wi-Fi networks, peer-to-peer Wi-Fi, and Bluetooth personal area networks (by: http://nshipster.com/multipeer-connectivity/